# I have a video I made in Premiere Pro that is like slides with 150MB audio. How can I export it to a reasonable size?

Tags: premiere

I have a video I made in Premiere Pro that is like slides with 150MB audio. How can I export it to a reasonable size?

When I try to export it, it exports to a size of 7GB

I could perhaps do something with some other software to make it smaller, but i'm wondering if premiere pro has any option?

If not then what do you suggest I can do to other software to make it smaller?

The video portion is just slides showing text, and the slides some change after 5 seconds near the start, then every 5 minutes or so.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this question asked a few times here, see [Best export settings for still image with audio](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/32172/best-export-settings-for-still-image-with-audio/32177#32177) and also [Upload edited video to YouTube](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/30128/upload-edited-video-to-youtube/30130#30130) - I suspect it has been asked other times as well.

Most of the end-user / commercially available encoders require a "broadcast" standard frame rate (25fps/30fps/etc), and the outputting of all those frames ramps up the file size. Some online services seem to be using variable frame rate (VFR) encoders (see Facebook, referenced in the "edited video to YouTube" link above), which just encode the still frames each time they change (sometimes with minutes between each new frame), and drastically reduce the file sizes. If anyone knows of such an encoder being available to the general public, that is the answer to all of these questions - I'm yet to find one.

Without a VFR encoder, you're stuck with one of the generally available codecs like H.264, where all you can really do is just push the compression as hard as you can before the image turns to rubbish, but you're still going to get quite large files out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably chose

File → Export → Movie

It exported your video as an AVI file, creating the best quality video, *but the output file is very large.*

*(This a little confusing option is for mastering purposes, or if you want to be able to edit the resulting video again without the quality lost.)*

Use

**File → Export → Adobe Media Encoder**

instead.

The “Export Settings” window opens, and you may choose a format from the drop-down menu at the top right of the window.

You can export it as Flash, Windows Media, Real Media, QuickTime, and a variety of MPEG formats including Blu-ray and H.264.

These options give more compressed, much smaller file size.

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing either the resolution or the duration of the video is hard to know if that is a good file size or not. But in any case, you need to define a CODEC and a container for your video. And define the resolution of the project.

A typical one is FULL HD (1920x1080px) and the most used container is Mp4 with an h264 and ACC codecs for video and audio.

You could totally lower your framerate to even 1 pers second if you have direct cuts in between slides, but if the video has transitions between the slides you can not. Use 24Fps.

---

Of course, you already did your work, next time you can actually do it in a presentation program, and export it from there.

Comment: of course it's not a good file size, the audio is 150MB or so.  Some slides shouldn't make it 7GB.  There are no transitions, as I said, it's just slides/images and of text.  Re changing frame rate, I understand that option would be under "interpret footage" but that option is greyed out https://i.imgur.com/hCpPRwG.png